# what should be value of tokenswapStateAccount when trying to swap

Tags: spl-token, rpc, spl-token-program, swap

I am using node js  @solana/web3 and @solana/spl-token and spl-token-swap libraries to perform a swap of token. I am confused with what should be the value of tokenSwapStateAccount and where would I get it ? Can anyone help me with this ?

> ```
> const swapInstruction = TokenSwap.swapInstruction(
>   tokenSwapStateAccount,
>   swapAuthority,
>   userPublicKey,
>   userTokenA,
>   poolTokenA,
>   poolTokenB,
>   userTokenB,
>   poolMint,
>   feeAccount,
>   null,
>   TOKEN_SWAP_PROGRAM_ID,
>   TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
>   amount * 10 ** MintInfoTokenA.decimals,
>   0
> )
>
> transaction.add(swapInstruction)
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tokenSwapStateAccount` refers to the "pool" account that describes things like the token mints involved in the pool and the mint for the LP tokens.

You can see how it's created in the spl-token-swap tests at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/74df99dec0309a682ce29765e76f67be30474ea9/token-swap/js/test/main.test.ts#L131